# How to synchronize two processes by posix named semaphore?

Tags: c, synchronization, semaphore

Suppose there are two processes and their pids are known by each other:

```
void proc_1(){
    printf("1\n");
    printf("3\n");
}

void proc_2(){
    printf("2\n");
    printf("4\n");
}
```

How to use posix named semaphore to synchronize above processes so that the output will look like:

1
2
3
4

My first thought is that(suppose there are two semaphores, sem_1, sem_2 and both of their initial value are 0):

```
void proc_1(){
    printf("1\n");
    sem_post(sem_2);
    sem_wait(sem_1)
    printf("3\n");
    exit(0);
}

void proc_2(){
    sem_wait(sem_2);
    printf("2\n");
    sem_post(sem_1);
    waitpid(pid_1);
    printf("4\n");
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`waitpid(pid_1)` could only work if process 1 were a child of process 2.
This version doesn't have that limitation:

```
void proc_1()
{
    printf("1\n");
    sem_post(sem_2);
    sem_wait(sem_1);
    printf("3\n");
    sem_post(sem_2);
}

void proc_2()
{
    sem_wait(sem_2);
    printf("2\n");
    sem_post(sem_1);
    sem_wait(sem_2);
    printf("4\n");
}
```